# Momentarily issue while launching selenium testing framework on Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

[image]

I have created a Selenium (Java) framework for my regression test cases. Things are working fine. Only problem is whenever i executes testcases in Chrome Browser, it launches Chrome and Shows "data;" (as shown in the image) in the address bar till it passes actual URL onto it. 
Can anyone please let me know the reason for it and any solution?

Comment: What's the problem? That just keeps Chrome from loading anything on startup.

Comment: That is chrome default behavior with selenium web driver. That will not affect your testing. Please let us know if you are getting any other specific issue.

Comment: for me, it seems that there is some initialization issue or something. I think, it should not be there. Because, when i run the same program on other browsers like IE or FF, nothing of such sorts are present and directly  URL gets passed.

Comment: This is the standard behaviour of ChromeDriver. It behaves differently from FirefoxDriver and IEDriver. It has no bearing on your tests - you cannot stop this from happening.

Comment: Thanks Mark ,chrylis, helping... for providing your thought onto my problem. But i am still curious to know the reason for it.

Comment: Another problem related to this issue: Today, when i tried to run my framework on another machine. In Firefox , it works. But when i run the same in Chrome, it launched the Chrome browser and just shows "Data;" (as shown in the image above), but it does not passed the URL